# TypeError: this is undefined - React JS, Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to implement a simple react component which change name on clicking. I am getting the error `Error - TypeError: this is undefined` while loading my page which has below react component. The error seems to be in the `setState` line.

```
class Layer5 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {buttonstate: false};

  }

  componentDidMount() {

  }

  componentWillUnmount() {

  }

  handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({buttonstate: !this.state.buttonstate});      
  }

  render() {
    var icon = this.state.buttonstate ? 'images/image1.png' : 'images/image2.jpg';

    return (
      <div className="layer5">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}><img src={icon} ></img></a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: on which line? chances are it's in `handleClick` ... common solution is to have the line `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)` inside the constructor - because `this` is tricky with event handlers

Comment: This article explains 5 different approaches to solve this issue with pros and cons: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Either a) create a property lexically closed over the instance (`this`) using an arrow function or b) use `.bind`.

Do one or the other.
Either a)

```
class Layer5 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.handleClick = e => {
      e.preventDefault();

      this.setState({buttonstate: !this.state.buttonstate});
    };
  }
}
```

or b)

```
render() {
    const icon = this.state.buttonstate ? 'images/image1.png' : 'images/image2.jpg';

    return <div className="layer5">
        <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}>
          <img src={icon} >
          </img>
        </a>
      </div>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import React from 'react'

class UsernameForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: ''
    }
    this.onchange=this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}
onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        username: e.target.value
    })
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type='text'placeholder='What is your username ?' onChange={this.onChange} />
                <input type='submit' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default UsernameForm

> I am getting error: this is undefined
>
> So that i bind this on {this.onChange} see the solution below

```
import React from 'react'


class UsernameForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        username: ''
    }
    this.onchange=this.onChange.bind(this)
    this.onSubmit=this.onSubmit.bind(this)
}

onChange(e) {
    this.setState({
        username: e.target.value
    })
}

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.props.onSubmit(this.state.username)
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <input type='text'placeholder='What is your username ?' onChange={this.onChange.bind(this)} />
                <input type='submit' />
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

}

export default UsernameForm